# Sumif on a calculated range

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an aggregation and graphing tool in Excel. My data is pretty simple, but the transformation to make it graphable is not.

On Sheet1, I have rows in the form:

```
| Ch-x  | Theme-1  | Intensity-1  | Theme-2  | Intensity-2  |
```

The Themes-1, -2, etc. on each row will vary, though they are within a set of a dozen. This gives me one row per chapter.

On Sheet2, I want to transform this into:

```
+---------+------+------+------+
|      n  | Ch-1 | Ch-2 | Ch-3 | 
+---------+------+------+------+
| Theme-A |   8  |      |   1  |
+---------+------+------+------+
| Theme-B |   4  |   9  |      |
+---------+------+------+------+
| Theme-C |      |   2  |   7  |
+---------+------+------+------+
```

This can then be graphed to represent the intensities of the various themes between chapters.

To do this, I could manually create a bunch of sumif() functions that look at the right rows, but this is tedious, as it cannot rely on simply copying the function. The issue is partly only partly the flipping of the axes.

To make it copyable, I need a way of referencing the ranges in the sumif() that include a calculated part, which will be the sum of a hidden offset value (the n in the top left corner of the second table), and the chapter number: effectively (in cell B2):

`=sumif(Sheet1!range(B($A$1+B$1):D($A$1+B$1)), B$1, Sheet1!range(C($A$1+B$1):E($A$1+B$1))`

where I have used `range()` as a function concept that calculates the start and end positions.

How can I do that type of range definition/referencing?

Comment: Can you show the _actual_ data that would be used to create that transformed table?  And then lets take a step back from that sumif formula and think about the problem as a whole, because you are getting heavily into an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem by specifically asking about your attempted solution.

Comment: If you really think it will be easier to understand… I want to take a set of A-B pairs associated with each row and turn them into B-values for A-row, per a column associated with the source row,
While `sumif` is not particularly clean, it does a good job…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX` function can give you a range that you can use within `SUMIF`, e.g. using your example

`=SUMIF(INDEX(Sheet1!B:D,$A$1+B$1,0),B$1,INDEX(Sheet1!C:E,$A$1+B$1,0))`

Comment: Actually, per the question, `=SUMIF(INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$D,$A$1+B$1,0),$B1,INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$E,$A$1+B$1,0))` - but who's arguing?

Comment: Well apparently you understood this way better than I did